# Improving group by performance in mysql on large result sets

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by, query-performance

We have a large table, let's call it "Data", with ~2 billion rows, data is indexed by date, location, name. Each row has a 'score'.

We also have a table which contains all of the distinct dates in this table.

If I run a query like this:

```
SELECT  AVG(score)
    FROM  Data d
    WHERE  d.date IN (
        SELECT  today
            FROM  dates dt
            WHERE  dt.today > '2020-01-01'
              AND  dt.today <  '2020-06-01'
              AND  d.location = 'Location1');
```

This query returns in several seconds. If I then run the same query, but look for the average score grouped by name, the query takes minutes. i.e.

```
SELECT  d.name, AVG(score)
    FROM  Data d
    WHERE  d.date IN (
        SELECT  today
            FROM  dates dt
            WHERE  dt.today > '2020-01-01'
              AND  dt.today <  '2020-06-01'
              AND  d.location = 'Location1')
            GROUP BY  .d.name;
```

The number of distinct names is several hundred thousand, any techniques to improve the speed of a query like this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the `CREATE TABLE` statements of your tables (including the indices you have) and the result of an `EXPLAIN ...` query for your query.

Comment: Please read this:https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-performance/info Then please [edit] your question to give us more information. With a table that size, it's vital to know what indexes you have.

Comment: Note that I’m not trying to improve the speed of the first query, I’m trying to understand why the second one takes so much more time. I think it may be because it has to create temp tables on disk, but not sure how to avoid that.

Comment: With tables as big as yours you should learn as much as you can about SQL indexes. Read Marcus Windand's excellent https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all try this.

```
 CREATE INDEX data_name_score ON Data (location, date, name, score);
```

This [compound](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) [covering](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index) index should accelerate your query. For a table your size it will take some time to create. (Run it overnight, maybe?)

Why does this index improve your query's performance? Think of the index as a sorted list of all the values in all the columns of the index.

1. MySQL can random-access the index to find the first relevant row ... the first row with the `location` you chose and the `date` in the range you mentioned.
2. It can then step through the index sequentially, without referring back to the table at all, to satisfy the query. `name` and `score` are in the index.
3. As it steps through the index, lo and behold, the index items are in the ideal order to handle the `GROUP BY`. It encounters all the `score` values for the `name` with value `a`, then all the scores for `b`, and so forth. There's no need for an internal table with a row for each of your distinct names.

   Notice that if you said `MAX(score)` instead of `AVG(score)` your query could be satisfied by a so-called [*loose index scan*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html#loose-index-scan). Those are almost miraculously fast, even faster than the [*tight index scan*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html#tight-index-scan) your query will use.

Second, simplify your query like this.

```
SELECT d.name, AVG(score) avgscore 
  FROM Data d
 WHERE d.location = 'Location1'
   AND d.date >= '2020-01-01'
   AND d.date < '2020-06-01'
 GROUP BY d.name;
```

MySQL should be able to satisfy your query with a [range scan on the index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html#range-access-multi-part) I suggested.

And, beware, lots of single-column indexes are generally *harmful* to performance unless they are matched to actual queries you must perform.  Several single-column indexes are *not* the equivalent of a multi-column index.

As for why your query is slow without the index, you can use [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html) to get MySQL to tell you exactly how it satisfies the query. It probably has to examine a large fraction of the gigarows in your table to filter the ones you want and generate your results.

Comment: I understand that adding that index will improve the initial query, but will it improve the group by?

Comment: Ah, so by adding “value” columns to the index, even though you never group by the value, the group by doesnt have to access the table, just the index.

Answer (score 0):

- Missing a closing parenthesis.
- Use `JOIN dates ...`, not `IN ( SELECT ... )`
- Was Jan. 1 deliberately left out?